# Append multidimensional list in for loop where indices vary with loop iteration

Tags: python, arrays, list, for-loop, indexing

I would like to create a list into which a new value is placed every iteration. The list should have dimensions 3x4 (3 rows, 4 columns). I want to iterate x, and for each x, the list should be filled vertically with three values. (Thus, when x = 1, I would like to fill the first index position [1, 1] of the list with the value *percentage_a*. *percentage_b* should then fill column 1 (as x is still 1) and row 2. The same for *percentage_c* for column 1, row 3). Then x goes up by one, and the second column of the list should be filled and so on.
I have code as follows:

```
list = []

for x in range(1, 4)
    a = 2
    b = 1
    c = 1
    sum = 4
    percentage_a = a / 4
    percentage_b = b / 4
    percentage_c = c / 4
    list.insert([x, 1], int(percentage_a))
    list.insert([x, 2], int(percentage_b))
    list.insert([x, 3], int(percentage_c))
```

I would wish for output like this:

```
[0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5
0.25 0.25 0.25 0.25
0.25 0.25 0.25 0.25]
```

I am open to do this any way (list, numpy)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using nested lists:

Each inner list is one row. In Python and most other programming languages, the index of arrays/lists/etc. starts with 0, not 1.

```
l = [[],[],[]]

a = 2
b = 1
c = 1
percentage_a = a / 4
percentage_b = b / 4
percentage_c = c / 4

for i in range(4):
    l[0].append(percentage_a)
    l[1].append(percentage_b)
    l[2].append(percentage_c)
```

The result of `l` will then be:

```
[[0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5],
 [0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25],
 [0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

```
import numpy as np

a = 2
b = 1
c = 1
percentage_a = a / 4
percentage_b = b / 4
percentage_c = c / 4

## Option 1
l = np.empty(shape=(3,4))
for x in range(4):
    l[:,x]=[percentage_a,percentage_b,percentage_c]

## Option 2, a bit shorter
l = np.array([[percentage_a,percentage_b,percentage_c] for i in range(4)]).T
```

This returns a 2D numpy array

```
array([[0.5 , 0.5 , 0.5 , 0.5 ],
       [0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25],
       [0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25]])
```

Note, you can convert it to a list of lists using `l.tolist()` or flatten your output to a single list using `l.flatten()` depending on what you actually need.